# Oracle defaultNChar=true SLOW on NCHAR/NVARCHAR2

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, nvarchar

I am using a JDBC Prepared Statement with a bunch of parameters using setString(pos, value). The underlying columns on the tables are all NCHAR and NVARCHAR2. I have set the Oracle JDBC driver's "defaultNChar=true" so that Oracle DB would always treat my parameters as national language characters. The driver file is "ojdbc6.jar".

My problem: My parametrized query is **extremely slow with "defaultNChar=true"**. But as soon as I set **"defaultNChar=false" the query is ultra fast** (3 seconds).

Query usage looks like that:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE_ERROR(MY_NAME,MY_FLAG,MY_VALUE) "
                        + "SELECT ? AS MY_NAME,"
                        + "? AS MY_FLAG,v.MY_VALUE"
                        + " FROM OTHER_TABLE v"
                        + " JOIN ( SELECT * FROM ... iv ... WHERE iv.MY_NAME = ? ) rule1 "
                        + " ON v.\"MY_NAME\"=rule1.\"MY_NAME\" AND v.\"MY_VALUE\"=rule1.\"MY_VALUE\""
                        + " WHERE rule1.\"MY_NAME\" = ? AND v.\"MY_VALUE\" = ?";

preStatement = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
int count = 1;
for (String p : params)
{
        // SLOW
        //preStatement.setNString (count++, p);
        // SLOW
        //preStatement.setObject (count++, p, Types.NVARCHAR);
        // SLOW
        preStatement.setString (count++, p);
}
```

I have been trying to find the root cause of why my prepared statements executed against an "Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production" DB are slow with a JDBC driver "Oracle JDBC driver, 11.2.0.3.0". I could not find any clue!

I even got the DB NLS config hoping to find anything, but I am not sure here either:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP    BINARY
```

Please help!

Thanks,
G.

UPDATE: It looks like the query is stuck when using "defaultNChar=true" somehow. I am seeing this when using JConsole:

```
Total blocked: 1  Total waited: 1

Stack trace: 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:312)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:257)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:182)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:99)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:121)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:77)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1173)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:309)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:200)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:543)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:238)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1446)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1757)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4372)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4539)
   - locked oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7f2315e5
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:5577)
com.mycompany.test.DriverTest.fireStatement(DriverTest.java:253)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreparedStatement.setFormOfUse` for performance issue:

> However, if you set defaultNChar to true and then access CHAR columns,
>   then the database will implicitly convert all CHAR data into NCHAR.
>   This conversion has a substantial performance impact. To avoid this,
>   call setFormOfUse(4,OraclePreparedStatement.FORM_CHAR) for each CHAR
>   column referred to in the statement. For example:
>
> ```java
>     PreparedStatement pstmt =
>     conn.prepareStatement("insert into TEST values(?,?,?)");
>     pstmt.setInt(1, 1); // NUMBER column
>     pstmt.setString(2, myUnicodeString1); // NVARCHAR2 column
>     pstmt.setString(3, myUnicodeString2); // NCHAR column
>     pstmt.setFormOfUse(4, OraclePreparedStatement.FORM_CHAR);
>     pstmt.setString(4, myString); // CHAR column
>     pstmt.execute();
> ```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/global.htm#CHDHHJDB