# Slower Oracle Query when called by JDBC instead SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, query-optimization

I am using the JDBC driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
The server URL ist passed as: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:port/VMP"

I have a 3 columns in the table:

[image]

Additionally there is only a primary key index on the table.

The Query is:

```
SELECT SN_SERIALNR,
       SN_ORDER_ID
FROM test_table
WHERE SN_SITE_ID=1
AND SN_ORDER_ID='xxx'
```

When I run the query in the SQL developer it needs like 500ms to execute.
But when I execute the query from my external programm and run it with the JDBC it needs like 4000ms.

Adding an index with SN_SITE_ID and SN_ORDER_ID, SN_SERIALNR improves the SQL developer query to 300ms but does not change the JDBC execution.

My tests shew, that the execution duration of the JDBC call would be reduced to the sql developer duration, if the column type is changed to varchar2 instead of nvarchar.

Any idea how to proceed to improve the duration of the JDBC call without changing the column data type?

The table contains around 1.3 million rows and the query result for the tested SN_ORDER_ID contains 3700 rows

To execute the query I am using the function "Execute batch" (right button)
[image]

Initially I noticed the performance problem in the SAP MII application.
In that software I have two options to execute a query

1. with typed parameters which generates a prepared statement for the query with variables. In there I can just select "String" as variable datatype (no difference between nvarchar and varchar)
2. execute without variables and to send the query directly to the dbms.

In the second option without variables the query also runs 10x faster regarding nvarchar columns.

Is there a possibility to force the jdbc always to use nvarchar for string?
My whole data model uses nvarchar for string values, so it would be no problem to make such a setting.

Due to the hints in the comment I checked the bindings. The parameter :2 is a varchar2. The elapsed time is 4 seconds.

[image]

[image]

Because of unknown reason, the query is now much faster on the development system (which I prepared with the same data as on the productive system)

- same bindings, same result, as well varchar2
- on the "slow" productive system the query is still executed very fast if no prepared statement is used

Productive system, no usage of bindings: 54ms elapsed time
[image]

Development system with bindings: Elapsed time is 10 ms instead 4000 ms (Productive system).

[image]
[image]

Comment: SQL Developer will fetch the rows in batches and only loads the first batch (I think that 500 rows is the default setting) and then will lazy-load the next batch when you scroll down to the bottom of the first batch. Are you sure you are comparing like-for-like? If SQL Developer is loading 500 rows and Java is loading 3700 rows then taking ~8 times longer for ~8 times more data is reasonable.

Comment: SQL developer uses JDBC as the connectivity, so it should have the same "raw" performance compared to your code. Try to emulate the same code by putting `:varname` in place of your exact value to make SQL developer to interpret your statement as the prepared statement and use the same bind variables concept as in your code. Also note the above comment about first rows returned by SQL developer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a bind variable and type it as nvarchar2 when the column is varchar2 (or vice-versa), Oracle has to apply an internal conversion function against the column to make it match the datatype of the bind variable to be able to compare it to the bind variable value. That implicit function disables the use of indexes.

So making your bind variable on the JDBC side match the column datatype in the database is the right solution. You shouldn't be forced to change the table... there must be a way to select the appropriate bind variable type in your client.

If you want more exact diagnostics to verify that this is the issue, simply query `v$sql` to find your SQL statement in the shared pool, get the `sql_id`, and then query `v$sql_bind_capture WHERE sql_id = {your sql id}` and look at the datatype of each bind variable. Compare to the datatype of the corresponding column in your table. If they are not exactly the same, that's your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using the Execute Script which in my undestanding loads all the rows. The normal "Play" Button does it per batch.

Comment: Okay, sure. I don't use that product myself, but it's a common mistake folks make. I edited my answer with some steps you can take to determine whether datatype mismatch is in fact the problem as I expect it is.

Comment: Thx for the hint, sounds like a good solution. I am not very familiar how to query that information. My QUERY SELECT * FROM V$SQL leads to an error ORA-00942: Table or view not found. I found by google that I miss the required rights. I wil lask the administrator to grant me the required privileges

Comment: You'd need to ask for the "select any dictionary" priv. But it might be easier to just skip this and try the type change on your JDBC client . If it fixes your problem, you know that was the issue.

Comment: I do not know how to make a type change on the jdbc client side. Is there a general setting available?

Comment: The binding info tells me that the datatype of the passed parameter is varchar2. The column type on the database is nvarchar2.

Comment: then that is your issue. either use nvarchar2 (national character set string) on the jdbc side, or change the table column type, OR create a function-based index on the column that does the conversion

Comment: Try this:  "WHERE sn_order_id = TO_NCHAR(:var)" where :var is  the bind variable

Comment: Very interesting @Paul W. I just checked, thanks to you, and I have decided to change all my nvarchar2 to varchar2 (after double checking my db is AL32UTF8...). Many thanks.

Comment: @Paul: Do you think that a function index is a possible solution here? After overthinking the information I assume that nvarchar cannot be converted varchar. And that the index actually still should work, since the dbms should implicit convert the varchar to nvarchar and afterwards use the index. Anyway I will try out your hint with the TO_NCHAR.

Comment: It does not help to add TO_NCHAR. The binding variable remains VARCHAR and the dbms decides not to use the index. When not using binding variables, the dbms is using the index by U'xx' as order-id

Comment: I really think you're going to have to make your client datatypes match the database datatypes. It is definitely possible to do that, and that's the real solution.

Comment: I could not find out, how to do that within the connection string. I cannot change the behaviour of the SAP MII which uses the setString Method to set the variable for the prepared statement. Somehow the JDBC converts it to VARCHAR2 instead of NVARCHAR2. I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398301/oracle-defaultnchar-true-slow-on-nchar-nvarchar2 . But I find even more infos that this settings leads somehow to slower queries. Moreover I would need to set it inside the connection string and not for the whole application